# MVC5: Having Trouble with Filtering Results And Pagination Together

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Index View (list) that I have added pagination to, and it works perfectly.  I have other views (lists) that have an html search box that passes a value back to the controller and also works perfectly.  But, when I try to have both on the same view . . I get a null reference error.

Error Message
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

This is the line generating the error:

```
var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.ItemDescription.Contains(searchString));
```

This is the asp/html search box on the index view

```
form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index">
<p>
    Search Catalog Files: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
```

And this is my Index Controller that has the pagination and searchString

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {



         var supplies = db.ICS_Supplies.OrderByDescending(g => g.Supplies_ID).ToList();
        var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.ItemDescription.Contains(searchString));
        var model = new PagedList<ICS_Supplies>(catalogs, 1, 10);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
         {

            catalogs = catalogs.Where(s => s.ItemDescription.Contains(searchString));
         }
        return View(model);

    }
```

Does this have anything to do with async?  Do I need to use the following?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string searchString)
```

Or perhaps do I have things in the wrong order?  The page works fine, IF the SearchString text box has text in it . . but when the page tries to load for the first time, it fails.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if searchString is null before execute

```cs
var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.ItemDescription.Contains(searchString ?? string.Empty));
```

Comment: Thank you!  That did the trick.  I really appreciate your help.